# Stock date in a string then split it for tests

Tags: bash, date, split

I have some operations to do on files last modified on a specific date. I would like to get the date, stock it in a string, then split it to test if the day corresponds to what I want.
So far, I've been trying things like that:

```
    #!/bin/bash

for i in {45..236}; do
    nom=M$i
    chem=/Users/nfs/helene/soft/metAMOS-1.5rc3/$nom.fastq/Assemble/out
    if [ -e $chem ]; then
        IN= $(date -r $chem)
        arr=(${IN//\ / })
        if [[ ${arr[1]} == 'juin' && ${arr[2]} == '10' ]]; then
            echo $nom
            #cp $chem/proba.faa /Users/nfs/helene/metagenomes/DB/$nom.faa
        fi
    fi
done
exit 0
```

But it seems like the date isn't well stocked in $IN, and I'm not sure about the space-spliting either..

Comment: Can you give an example of expected output. Also why would you have to test the day corresponds to what you want if you already searched for it ?

Comment: All the directory corresponding to my M$i names are not last modified the same day, and I want to copy a file (see the commented line) only from the directories modified on the date chosen, so I have to test it.

Comment: So you're searching for directories that are modified not files ?

Comment: Yes that's it. Sorry I just realised I wrote 'files' on my post

Comment: Still dont really understand what you want, this will find directories modified on May 23 `ls -lt | grep 'May 23' | grep ^d |awk '{print $9}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simple mistake is that you didn't place your assignment adjacent to `=`. It must be:

```
    IN=$(date -r $chem)
```

And here's a simplified suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {45..236}; do
    nom="M${i}"
    chem="/Users/nfs/helene/soft/metAMOS-1.5rc3/${nom}.fastq/Assemble/out"
    if [[ -e $chem ]]; then
        read month day < <(exec date -r "$chem" '+%b %d')
        if [[ $month == 'Jun' && $day == 10 ]]; then
            echo "$nom"
            # cp "$chem/proba.faa" "/Users/nfs/helene/metagenomes/DB/$nom.faa"
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

*****  See `date --help` for a list of formats.
  *****  `<()` is a form of Process Substitution. Check Bash's manual for it.
  *****  Always place your arguments around double quotes when they have variables to avoid word splitting.